# Terminal startup information

Tags: java, gnome-terminal

When I startup my terminal, I always get a bunch of "help" information about java. How can I get rid of this? I am not even sure what package I installed that changed what is executed on startup. Any help or ideas on where to look would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of ignored this for a while ... and then realized that I had the following in `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)
```

I removed this as unnecessary, and YAY! no more java messages. It is still in my path as executable, so no need to additionally export it. For anyone out there that may come across this, don't forget to run the following after making any changes to that file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```